# Regex Keep All After parentheses ")"

Tags: regex, parentheses

I want to remove with regex everything before ")" and the ")" but keep the rest.

This what I have done so far. This does what I want except it keeps the ")" which I don't want.

```
^[^\\)]+
```

Example Text:

```
#tags (word) this a example where i run the regex.
```

After Regexing I have:

```
) this a example where i run the regex.
```

I want:

```
this a example where i run the regex.
```

I need to remove the ")" or ") " if it has space after the ")".

Comment: Add the closing parentheses, `^[^)]*\)` (or `^[^)]*\)\s*`)

Comment: Thanks@WiktorStribiżew '(^[^)]*\\)\s*)' seems to work fine for my project, with or without spaces. I don't see any option to mark your answer as the best.(i am new here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know which language you're using you'll want to escape the backslashes appropriately for your language.

The regex you want is `^[^\)]*\) ?`. [See example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DoFjEo/1)

The `^` anchors to the beginning of the string.
`[^\)]` finds any character that's not a `)`. The `*` matches that 0 or more times.
The `\)` matches a literal paren. 
And the `<space>?` matches 0 or 1 spaces. `<space>*` would match 0 or more spaces.

Comment: Thank's it's working. I use it inside a wordpress plugin so i think it is in php language. I also like this from comment above '(^[^)]*\\)\s*)'  cause i can remove more spaces after parenthesis.